# Form reset not happen after page auot refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a Iframe which has a form with text fields.This form is created by php script. The parent page refresh auto, continuously.

```
<form id="form"  method="post" action="test.php?vid='.$vid.'">
<table border="1" width="100%"  style="border-collapse:collapse">
<tr>
<th class="col-header list">Distance </th>
<th class="col-header list">Service</th>
<th class="col-header list">Recipient</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td >
<input type="text" class="input" id="cdistance" name="cdistance" />
</td>
<td nowrap class="list">
<input type="text" class="input" id="service" name="service" />
</td>
<td nowrap class="list">
<input type="text" class="input" id="destination" name="destination" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" colspan="3" style="background:#e0e0e0;">
<input type="submit" class="btn" name="add" id="add" value="Add New"/>
<input type="hidden" name="distance_unit" value="'.$distance.'" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

To avoid user entered data loosing ('before hit submit') I used   query code in parent page to get those entered text in Iframe's form and add them back to text fields after page refreshed.

My problem is when the user hit the submit button after page refreshed  text fields are not cleared (form not reset) but data submitted successfully.So I tried to reset the form by `$('#form')[0].reset()`. This is the error I got

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reset' of undefined

Also tried `$('#textVal').val('');` to empty text fields. But still the data remaining in text fields.

Note: The form is reset if the user hit submit button before refreshed. Does anyone need more details please let me know.

Any solution for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain your form has an `id="form"` ? `.reset()` should work but you have to make sure you are using the correct selector.

Comment: post your form here.

Comment: @Growiel yes form id is correct.

Comment: Can you provide us with a little bit of your HTML markup ?

Comment: I added part of the form here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#form').trigger("reset");
```

Comment: Even if you select by id with `$('#form')`, you still have to use `$('#form')[0]` to get the real HTMLFormObject and not the jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks. Got confused.

Comment: I tried $('#form')[0].trigger("reset"); and not worked.

Answer (score 0):

All the documentation you'll find about `.reset()` is misleading. It reset forms values only if there is no `value` attribute set.

I made a test in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bj2z2x14/.

When you click on submit, I first display the value of your hidden "distance_unit" field, I then clear the form using `$('#form')[0].reset();` and re-display the value, which is still set because of the `value` attribute.

If you want to clear the fields for which you specify a value, you have to do it manually with something like this:

```
$('#form').find('input:not([type="submit"])').val('');
```

This will reset every input in the form except the submit button (so you don't lose the button text).
You can see it in action in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bj2z2x14/1/